# Distributing family tree as image - security?

Tags: family-tree, publishing, privacy

I just created a huge family tree using mind-mapping tools, not common geneology tools. I'd like to distribute this to relatives as a PNG. I'm concerned about security. What should not be in a tree that might leak into the public?

The tree has nothing but last names, first names, and relationships. There are no photos, dates, locations, or any other data.

Not so much anymore, but "mother's maiden name" has been a security question in too many places for decades. There are lots of kids' names in the image too, of course. Is this data still sensitive?

The image will be posted in a private website, with a password to protect it, and with instructions on the page about not publishing it anywhere. But I'm still concerned that some random person might innocently/stupidly post the image somewhere - "hey, look at my huge family!".

Am I doing what is reasonable given industry/community standards for this? Or am I missing some protocol that everyone here knows and I haven't learned yet? :)

I am not pursuing geneology as a hobby. My goal as an older member of the family has been to create a base resource for others who may wish to pursue details now or in the future. So I'm not yet informed on norms within this community. Thanks for bearing with me.